# Html / CSS web contents blend when restoring-down the page

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I have created this web page using html, CSS and bootstrap, everything is okay on large and medium screen, but when I restore-down to small screen (col-12 and col-sm-12) the features and services sections blend, I tried everything I don't know how to fix it.

here is some code, I hope it is clear for you guys:

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: "Lucida Fax", sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .header .content-box {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(img/Webz.jpeg);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .menu {
      display: inline-flex;
    }

    .menu button {
      width: 75px;
      height: 35px;
    }

    .menu img {
      width: 147px;
      height: 147px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 1px;
    }

    .menu button {
      background: #ff4d73;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      border: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 70px;
      top: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu button .fa {
      margin-right: 7px;
    }

    .banner-text {
      color: whitesmoke;
      margin: 14%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .banner-text h2 {
      font-size: 37px;
    }

    .banner-text p {
      font-size: 15px;
      margin: 25px;
    }

    .banner-text a {
      border: 1px solid #ff4d73;
      padding: 7px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      background: #ff4d73;
      transition: .70s;
    }

    .banner-text a:hover {
      background: transparent;
    }

    .service .content-box {
      background: whitesmoke;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .service h1::after {
      content: '';
      background: #ff4d73;
      display: block;
      height: 3px;
      width: 190px;
      margin: 21px auto 50px;
    }

    .services .icon {
      font-size: 37px;
      margin: 21px auto;
      height: 55px;
      width: 55px;
      border: 1px solid #ff4d73;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: #ff4d73;
    }

    .services p {
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      color: #777;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .services span {
      color: #ff4d73;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: medium;
    }

    .services .col-md-3:hover {
      background: #ff4d73;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .services .col-md-3:hover p {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .services .col-md-3:hover span {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .services .col-md-3:hover .icon {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }

    li {
      padding-left: 35px;
    }

    .features .content-box {
      background: white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .features h2 {
      margin: 49px;
      padding-top: 111px;
    }

    .features h2::after {
      content: '';
      background: #ff4d73;
      display: block;
      height: 3px;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 13px 7px 51px;
    }

    .features ul {
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 33px;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .features ul li {
      position: relative;
      line-height: 33px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

    .features ul li::before {
      content: '';
      height: 7px;
      width: 7px;
      background: #ff4d73;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      margin-right: 19px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    img {
      height: 57%;
      width: 85%;
      margin-top: 29%;
    }

    .footer .content-box {
      background: whitesmoke;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .footer h1::after {
      content: '';
      background: #ff4d73;
      display: block;
      height: 3px;
      width: 190px;
      margin: 21px auto 50px;
    }

    .form-control {
      margin: 17px;
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      border: none !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }

     ::placeholder {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .contact-form button {
      border: none !important;
      background: #ff4d73 !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-left: 27px;
    }

    .contact-info .follow {
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 11px;
    }

    .contact-info .fa {
      margin: 10px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #ff4d73 !important;
    }

    .copyright {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .fa-heart-o {
      color: red;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .footer hr {
      margin-top: 217px;
      background: #ff4d73;
    }

    .form-group label {
      display: block;
    }

    .features {
      position: relative;
      top: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>


      <!-- Service Section -->

      <section class="service d-block">
        <div class="content-box">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Our Services</h1>
            <div class="row services d-block">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-renren"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Brand <span>Activation</span></h3>
                <p>
                  Subscribe to our Youtube channel to watch more videos on web development, UI design, photoshop and Digital marketing. Don't forget to press the bell icon and never miss any new video
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3 col-12 text-center">
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Employee <span>Activity</span></h3>
                <p>
                  Subscribe to our Youtube channel to watch more videos on web development, UI design, photoshop and Digital marketing. Don't forget to press the bell icon and never miss any new video
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3 col-12 text-center">
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-meetup"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Event <span>Organizer</span></h3>
                <p>
                  Subscribe to our Youtube channel to watch nmore videos on web development, UI design, photoshop and Digital marketing. Don't forget to press the bell icon and never miss any new video
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3 col-12 text-center">
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Video <span>Production</span></h3>
                <p>
                  Subscribe to our Youtube channel to watch nmore videos on web development, UI design, photoshop and Digital marketing. Don't forget to press the bell icon and never miss any new video
                </p>
              </div>

            </div>


          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

      <!-- Features Section -->

      <section class="features d-block">
        <div class="content-box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <h2>Features Are</h2>

                <ul>
                  <li>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text.</li>
                  <li>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text. </li>
                  <li>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text.</li>
                  <li>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text.</li>
                  <li>Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12  col-12">
                <img src="img/Webz2.jpeg" alt="Picture">
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content is bigger than 100vh, but you are limiting the container to that size. That is the overlapping reason.

```
.content-box {
  height: 100vh;
}
```